# Calling a Promise within a Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to call my getToken() promise asynchronously from my getEmployees() function but without making it asynchronous my getEmployees() function.

Please, any idea and thank you very much in advance.

**employee.service**

```
async getToken(): Promise < string > {
  return await this._auth._token();
}

getEmployees(): Observable < EmpleadoTarjeta[] > {

  const promiseSource = from(new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    await this.getToken().then(tokenUser => resolve(tokenUser));
  }));
  let token: any;
  promiseSource.subscribe(tokenPromise => token = tokenPromise);
  const httpHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    tokenJPA: token,
  });

  console.log(token);
  return this._httpClient
    .get<EmpleadoTarjeta[]>('API', { headers: httpHeaders }
    )
    .pipe(
      map(response => response.map(item => new EmpleadoTarjeta(item))),
      tap((empleados) => {
        this._empleados.next(empleados);
      })
    );
}
```

**_auth.service**

```
async _token(): Promise<string> {
    const auth = getAuth();
    return auth.currentUser.getIdTokenResult(true).then(async token => token.token);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
getEmpleados(): Observable<EmpleadoTarjeta[]> {
 // const token: any = from(this.getToken()).toPromise().then(tokenUser  
=> tokenUser);
const promiseSource: any = from(this.getToken());
const httpHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  tokenJPA: promiseSource.subscribe((tokenPromise: any) => {
    console.log(tokenPromise);
    return tokenPromise;
  }),
});

return this._httpClient
  .get<EmpleadoTarjeta[]>('http://localhost:5001/journeypadel/us-central1/fxManager_Empleados-empleadosRegistrados', { headers: httpHeaders }
  )
  .pipe(
    map(response => response.map(item => new EmpleadoTarjeta(item))),
    tap((empleados) => {
      this._empleados.next(empleados);
    })
  );
}
```

I did it this way and it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use it as:

```
const promiseSource = from(this.getToken());
```

**UPDATE**

```
getEmpleados(): Observable<EmpleadoTarjeta[]> {
  return from(this.getToken())
    .pipe(
      map((tokenUser) => new HttpHeaders({
        tokenJPA: tokenUser
      })),
      switchMap((httpHeaders) => this._httpClient
        .get<EmpleadoTarjeta[]>(
          'http://localhost:5001/journeypadel/us-central1/fxManager_Empleados-empleadosRegistrados',
          { headers: httpHeaders }
        )
        .pipe(
          map(response => response.map(item => new EmpleadoTarjeta(item))),
          tap((empleados) => {
            this._empleados.next(empleados);
          })
        ))
    );
}
```

Comment: see my update please

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, you helped me a lot, now I will have to study more about the rxjs operators to know how to apply them correctly, I really appreciate your help.